# If $x$ and $y$ are complex numbers and $x+y$ , $xy$ are algebraic numbers then how to prove that $x$ and $y$ are also algebraic numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, algebraic-numbers

I tries basic operations like multiplication and addition in a hope that i will get $x$ and $y$ out of $x+y$ and $xy$ but that didn't worked for me.Also i tried assuming a polynomial with rational coefficients which has $x+y$ as solution and another polynomial with rational coefficients which has $xy$ as solution and tried to find a polynomial which has $x$ as solution .But i couldn't do that also .

Comment: $x$ is a root of the polynomial $T^2 - \left(x+y\right) T + xyT = 0$, which has algebraic coefficients. Now I assume you know that a root of a nonzero polynomial with algebraic coefficients is algebraic.

Comment: @darijgrinberg  what are algebraic coefficients ?

Comment: They are $1$, $-(x+y)$ and $xy$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Only in this case (because in question i have mentioned $x+y$ and $xy$) or in general ?

Comment: @Shrijana: Coefficients that are algebraic numbers themselves.

Comment: @Shrijana In this case, because you wrote that $x+y$ and $xy$ are algebraic numbers.

Comment: @darijgrinberg what is $T$ ?

Comment: An indeterminate. You better not call it $x$ :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg I have not studied those stuffs , i now just basic like extension of field, dimension of a extension of the given field , algebraic numbers

Comment: How do you call the "x" in a polynomial if $x$ already stands for a number? I just named it $T$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I got what you want to say .But how do i prove that root of a nonzero polynomial with algebraic coefficients is algebraic .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simce $(x-y)^2=(x+y)^2-4xy$, the numbers $x$ and $y$ can be written as $\dfrac{x+y\pm\sqrt{(x+y)^2-4xy}}2$. Since the square root of an algebraic number is again an algebraic number, since the sum (and the difference) of algebraic numbers is again an algebraic number and since half an algebraic number is again an algebraic number, this proves that $x$ and $y$ are algebraic.